# Jquery and input value selector issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Html Code:

```
<input type="text" name="input-1" class="input-1" value="001 / 2007">
    <input type="button" id="asd" value="check">
```

JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#asd").click(function (){
        alert($("input[value='001 / 2007']").val());
        $("input[value='001 / 2007']").val("001-2007");
    });
});
```

The value changed through Jquery is not available to input[value...] selector after the change, it is still selects based on the old value.
Here is the live code http://jsfiddle.net/WwRVy/, 
So question is how to select input based on latest value?

Comment: you need to iterate through the inputs and filter

Comment: have you tried `$("input[value^='001']")` ..??

Comment: Can't you give your input an `id`, or just select the element based on its `name`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not select base on the name or just the class?

```
$("#asd").click(function (){
    $("input[name='input-1']").val("001-2007");
});
```

Comment: It is probably a snippet, that shows the issue of a selector not selecting what it supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Html Code:

```
<input type="text" name="input-1" class="input-1" value="001 / 2007">
<input type="button" id="asd" value="check">
```

JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
 $("#asd").click(function (){
    alert($("input").val());
    $("input").val();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, that jQuery `.val()` method changes the **property** value, while jQuery selector works with **attributes**. There are several workarounds, i.e. using `[0]` notation of jQuery object and change its `value` attribute or change it with `.attr()`:

```
$("input[value='001 / 2007']").attr("value", "001-2007");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WwRVy/2/)

P.S.: You'd better change the way you select that element, i.e. assign an `id` or a `class` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Its one of infamous JavaScript issues,
try

```
alert($('input[value="001 / 2007"]').val());
```

Notice the Single and Double quotes is swapped arround

Answer (score 0):

You want to do like

```
  $("input[value=001 / 2007]").val("001-2007");
```

Modified jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/WwRVy/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#asd").click(function (){
        var inputs = $('input').filter(function(){
            return $(this).val() == '001 / 2007';
        });
        alert(inputs.val());
        inputs.val("001-2007");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Maxde/1/)